# Google Auth Exchange Code , Referesh Token and Access Token

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-authentication, refresh-token

I am trying  to get the `refereh_token, access_token` using Google Auth Exchange Code, went through the documentation but it doesn't work, I am using a react-google-login for Auth and getting the `code` in response and i am passing the `code`
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token but its giving error

```
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

i have tried lots of ways

```
code=4%2FKxoYTS-jeq5-d6Lv7YvSz9ZrK0pJ_5lZsMExzNC1M0o&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=************&scope=&grant_type=authorization_code
```

frontend is reactjs and backend is nodejs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the ACCESS token using referesh token you have to call a api which will give you a new access token 
call a POST APi  https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token

pass the body as x-www-form-urlencoded i.e

Header as 
Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Body

client_secret : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxdxxxxxSSd'`<YourClientSecret>`

grant_type : refresh_token'

refresh_token : '1/DDPkddk514451xxxxxxxx' `<YourRefreshToken>`

client_id : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'  `<YourClientID>`

for more reference you can read this https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer